# How to use same method in two different classes (JavaFX with Scenebuilder)?

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, javafx, scenebuilder

I am currently experimenting with *JavaFX* and *SceneBuilder* in eclipse to create and design my own program. In my first class "StartController" I am using a method called **makeFadeIn**. Basically, when I click a button another page loads up with a fade effect.

This is the code from StartController.java (notice makeFadeIn):

```
public class StartController {

@FXML
private AnchorPane rootPane;

private void makeFadeIn() {
    FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition();
    fadeTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    fadeTransition.setNode(rootPane);
    fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
    fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
    fadeTransition.play();
}

@FXML
private void loadSecondPage(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    AnchorPane startPage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SecondController.fxml"));
    rootPane.getChildren().setAll(startPage);
    makeFadeIn();
}
```

Next, my other class loads up called "SecondController.java". In this class, I'm using the exact same method **makeFadeIn** (but I had to write it twice since it didn't let me run the program).

This is the code from SecondController.java:

```
public class SecondController {

@FXML
private AnchorPane rootPane;

private void makeFadeIn() {
    FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition();
    fadeTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    fadeTransition.setNode(rootPane);
    fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
    fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
    fadeTransition.play();
}

@FXML
private void loadFirstPage(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    AnchorPane startPage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StartController.fxml"));
    rootPane.getChildren().setAll(startPage);
}
```

My question is: can I somehow call the makeFadeIn method from the first class so I don't have to write it in my second class? I guess I need to inherit it in some way but I'm not sure how. I tried declaring it public instead of private but that did not help much.

Comment: When I have similar situations, I create a Utility class to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move this functionality to a base class:

```
public class BaseController {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    protected AnchorPane getRootPage() {
        return rootPane;
    }

    protected void makeFadeIn() {
        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition();
        fadeTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
        fadeTransition.setNode(rootPane);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
        fadeTransition.play();
    }
}
```

And then have the other controllers extend it:

```
public class StartController extends BaseController {

    @FXML
    private void loadSecondPage(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane startPage = 
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SecondController.fxml"));
        getRootPane().getChildren().setAll(startPage);
        makeFadeIn();
    }
}

public class SecondController extends BaseController {

    @FXML
    private void loadFirstPage(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane startPage = 
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StartController.fxml"));
        getRootPane().getChildren().setAll(startPage);
    }
}
```